# How to prevent external media from being mounted on my Mac without requiring a password?

Tags: usb, security, virus, anti-virus

I have a MacBook Air (macOS 12.6.7) that I travel with and use in public places. Is there a way to prevent a USB drive (or any other external physical network connection via cable) from becoming operational (able to execute something via a connection to my Mac)? At least without requiring my password?

I've tried Google searched on this but the best I can find is anti-virus software. Maybe that's enough, but I thought it would be nice to prevent a potential infection in the first place by blocking the connection.

Comment: Run as a non-admin.  Nothing can get installed unless you enter an admin  password

Comment: You could also just never connect anything. Disable WiFi, and don't plug in an ethernet cable to an adapter. Don't plug in a USB drive you don't have control over. If you have portable USB drives with important data, you should create an [encrypted drives](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/encrypt-protect-a-storage-device-password-dskutl35612/mac) which requires a password to mount. **Note:** the encryption requires you **reformat the external drive**.

Comment: @Allan that seems to be the best answer and kind of obvious.

Comment: Go ahead and type it up as an answer and ping me here in comments so I can upvote.

Comment: @Allan done, thanks for helping.

Comment: No worries!  Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest, most obvious answer was suggested in the comments to the question: Create and use a non-admin user when in situations that could be unsafe so that any physical connections made to my laptop would be unable to install or transfer anything without requiring an admin password.